# Convert if statement to ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I tried to convert these if statement to ternary:

```
var eatsPlants = false;
var eatsAnimals = true;

    if(eatsPlants){
      return 'herbivore';
    }else if(eatsAnimals){
      return 'carnivore';
    }else if(eatsPlants && eatsAnimals){
    return 'omnivore';
    }else{
     return undefined;
    }
```

Here's my solution:

```
var category = eatsPlants && eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore" : "carnivore" : undefined;

console.log(category);
```

But this doesnt work and it returns the error missing semicolon.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Joining that bunch of if's else's into one ternary operator is not a good idea. The ternary operator was made only as short hand for an if with one else statement

Comment: A ternary operator has *three* operands, not five, hence the name "ternary". Also, note that your original if/else structure will *never* return 'omnivore'.

Comment: Your original code does not work, because it will return `herbivore` even if both `eatsPlants` and `eatsAnimals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the remaining `if` conditions too

```
var category = eatsPlants && eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : eatsPlants? "herbivore" : eatsAnimals? "carnivore" : undefined;

console.log(category);
```

Comment: if I want to convert this
 ```let color;
    if (active) {
      color = '#000';
      if (title == 'Pause') {
        color = '#f00';
      } else {
        color = '#0f1';
      }
    }```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the other two conditions, and changed the order of checks (which is actually necessary to make it work, though). You'd do either

```
return (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals
  ? 'omnivore'
  : (eatsPlants
    ? 'herbivore'
    : (eatsAnimals
      ? 'carnivore'
      : undefined)));
```

or, avoiding the AND operation by nesting,

```
return (eatsPlants
  ? (eatsAnimals
    ? 'omnivore'
    : 'herbivore')
  : (eatsAnimals
    ? 'carnivore'
    : undefined));
```

(The parenthesis and indentation are optional, but strongly encouraged for readability, at least one of them).

Comment: Note that the first version (and the OP's if/else structure) won't ever return 'omnivore'.

Answer (score 0):

The js snippet shared by you may throw an error as return statement is not inside a function.

Have created  one more variable `returnResult` which will be assinged with new value depending on the condition.

!1 is false & !0 is true, void 0 is undefined

```
var eatsPlants = !1, eatsAnimals = !0, returnResult = "";
returnResult = eatsPlants ? "herbivore" : eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : eatsPlants && eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : void 0;
```